# RDF Turtle bnode object containing a list

Tags: rdf, owl, turtle-rdf

I'm trying to understand the following comma-separated object (source: [a biomedical ontology](https://github.com/BioPAX/specification/blob/master/Level3/specification/biopax-level3.owl)), whose second entry is a bnode.  I don't understand what the semicolons are doing inside the bnode.

```
:Conversion rdf:type owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf :Interaction ,
                        [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                          owl:onProperty :participant ;
                          owl:allValuesFrom :PhysicalEntity
                        ] ;
```

Comment: it's Turtle syntax and it means the subject is the blank node, i.e. the `[ ]` - it's an OWL class expression in particular a property restriction which simply means "the values of the `:participant` property are always a `:PhysicalEntity`"

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser!  I have a somewhat-related question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64039293/1798351.

Comment: More in general, commas separate triples that have the same subject and predicate and different objects, while semicolons separate triples with the same subject and different predicates and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comments provided above, the comma-separated list:

```
:Interaction ,
   [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
   owl:onProperty :participant ;
   owl:allValuesFrom :PhysicalEntity
   ] ;
```

defines two objects:

1. the subset relation to `:Interaction`
2. the `owl:Restriction` corresponding to the following blank node predicate list:

```
[ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty :participant ;
    owl:allValuesFrom :PhysicalEntity
    ] ;
```

The predicate list above defines an owl property restriction, an `owl:Class` which is [always defined anonymously](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/).

The three elements in this list correspond to the three pieces of information that specify a property restriction:

1. type declaration: `owl:Restriction`
2. property being constrained: `:participant`
3. constraint (in this case a value constraint): `owl:allValuesFrom :PhysicalEntity`