# SPARQL property paths based on a new property defined in a CONSTRUCT subquery

Tags: sparql, rdf

Given the following schema, "driver-passenger" lineages can be easily seen:

```
tp:trip a owl:Class ;
    rdfs:label "trip"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "an 'asymmetric encounter' where someone is driving another person."@en .

tp:driver a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:label "driver"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "has keys."@en ;
    rdfs:domain tp:trip ;
    rdfs:range tp:person .

tp:passenger a owl:ObjectProperty ;
    rdfs:label "passenger"@en ;
    rdfs:comment "has drinks."@en ;
    rdfs:domain tp:trip ;
    rdfs:range tp:person .
```

Consider the following data:

```
<alice> a tp:person .
<grace> a tp:person .
<tim> a tp:person .
<ruth> a tp:person .

<trip1> a tp:trip ;
    tp:participants   <alice> , <grace> ;
    tp:driver         <alice> ;
    tp:passenger         <grace> .

<trip2> a tp:trip ;
    tp:participants   <alice> , <tim> ;
    tp:driver         <alice> ;
    tp:passenger         <tim> .

<trip3> a tp:trip ;
    tp:participants   <tim> , <grace> ;
    tp:driver         <tim> ;
    tp:passenger         <grace> .

<trip4> a tp:trip ;
    tp:participants   <grace> , <ruth> ;
    tp:driver         <grace> ;
    tp:passenger         <ruth> .

<trip5> a tp:trip ;
    tp:participants   <grace> , <tim> ;
    tp:driver         <grace> ;
    tp:passenger         <tim> .
```

Now let a "driver-passenger descendent" be any `tp:passenger` at the end of a trip sequence where the `tp:passenger` of one trip is the `tp:driver` of the next trip

Ex. `<ruth>` is a descendent of `<alice>` according to the following sequence of trips:

`<trip2>` -> `<trip3>` -> `<trip4>`.

**Question:**
How to get the (ancestor,descendent) pairs of all driver-passenger lineages?

**Attempt 1:**
I initially tried the following CONSTRUCT subquery to define an object property: `tp:drove`, which can be easily used in a property path.  However, this did not work on my actual data:

```
SELECT ?originalDriver ?passengerDescendent
WHERE {
    ?originalDriver tp:drove+ ?passengerDescendent .
    {
        CONSTRUCT { ?d tp:drove ?p . }
        WHERE { ?t a tp:trip .
                ?t tp:driver ?d . 
                ?t tp:passenger ?p .}        
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2:**
I tried to create property path which expresses an ancestor as the driver of a passenger, but I don't think I've properly understood how this is supposed to work:

```
(tp:driver/^tp:passenger)+
```

---

**Regarding MWE:** Is there some kind of RDF sandbox that would allow me to create an MWE by defining a simple ontology like `tp` above, along with some sample data?  The following "playgrounds" are available but none of them seem to support defining a toy ontology: [SPARQL Playground](http://sparql-playground.sib.swiss/), [SPARQL Explorer](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%7D).

---

*Notes on related content:*

This question is directly related to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64039293/sparql-paths-where-the-subject-and-object-are-not-of-the-same-class), but no longer requires saving the paths themselves, a feature not directly supported by SPARQL 1.1.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698675/sparql-property-path-queries-with-arbitrary-properties) by Joshua Taylor seems relevant, but doesn't address the identification of specific types of paths, such as the lineages defined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems to do the trick:

```
select ?driver ?passenger where {
?driver (^tp:driver/tp:passenger)+ ?passenger .
filter( ?driver != ?passenger)
}
```

The filter condition can be removed if you want to also see relationships that lead back to the same person.

Comment: Thanks!  
However, on a query with actual data Virtuoso is complaining about lack of resources.  I tried the following modifications (still got 42000): 1) Limit 10 results, 2) wrapping initial selection in a subquery, 3) specifying a single IRI for the ?driver

Comment: instead of a subquery, could you use VALUES? . Could you try using increasing the memory limit to say 4G ? You could also use a limit of 100 to begin with.